# How to integrate twilio with ironpython?

Tags: python, twilio, ironpython

I have a code to implement inside ironpython2.7 using Twilio. However, I tried many things and they all seem to fail. for example, I copied Twilio module from my python site packages and located inside the ironpython directory:C:\Program Files (x86)\IronPython 2.7\Lib

the script

```
from twilio.rest import Client

# Your Account Sid and Auth Token from twilio.com/console
# DANGER! This is insecure. See http://twil.io/secure
account_sid = '#################'
auth_token = '###########'
client = Client(account_sid, auth_token)

message = client.messages \
            .create(
                 body="this an autmated sms testing  twilio's {} and {} 
api".format("a","b"),
                 from_='+#########',
                 to='+##########'
             )

print(message.sid)
```

I am getting the following error:

```
Warning: IronPythonEvaluator.EvaluateIronPythonScript operation failed. 
Traceback (most recent call last):
File "<string>", line 16, in <module>
File "C:\Program Files (x86)\IronPython 2.7\Lib\twilio\rest\__init__.py", 
line 12, in <module>
File "C:\Program Files (x86)\IronPython 
2.7\Lib\twilio\base\exceptions.py", line 4, in <module>
ImportError: No module named six
```

any ideas on how to solve this issue?

Thank you in advance

Comment: the error says that the module named "six" is missing. have you installed it?

Comment: I did bu then i got another error:

Comment: is there a better way to fix it? like install twilio directly to ironpython 2.7. my strategy is just copying the packages from python directory and placing them in ironpython dir